Ravi Vakil's jigsaw notation of quotient groups - can it be used to "geometrically" prove theorems?
I just discovered this: Puzzling through exact sequences, a picture book when I'm learning abstract algebra.
This thing astonishes me - it demonstrates a lot of isomorphism theorems with only jigsaw puzzle notations, without using any coset computations.
It then makes me wonder: can we actually prove anything new with this? Is this just a notation, like a commutative diagram, that requires exterior reasoning (like coset computations) to justify? Or is it an actual machine, with a few theorems about the basic rules of the diagram powering it, that proves tens of isomorphism theorems upon drawing a jigsaw diagram and writing nothing?
For example, can we somehow make this a valid proof?

Theorem 1. (Third isomorphism theorem) If $C\subset B\subset A$, then $(A/C)/(B/C)=A/B$.
Proof. $\quad$ By the following picture, since they are both the right block, they are isomorphic.

$\square$


Without additional care it seems like this notation could easily "prove," for example, that if $H_1 \cong H_2$ are two isomorphic normal subgroups of a group $G$ then $G/H_1 \cong G/H_2$, which is not true. It also seems to suggest that if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, which is also not true. So without more details I would consider this a useful but also treacherous mnemonic device.
